# How can I protect a directory using .htaccess?

Tags: security, apache, .htaccess

How can I protect a folder using .htaccess? I want the folder `/files/myfiles` to only be accessed by the server, not by a user? How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this thing: **Options -Indexes** is hiding directory listing

Answer (score 3):

Add the `.htaccess` file to `/files/myfiles` folder with the following in it:

```
deny from all
```

Internally when your scripts look for files they aren't going through Apache, only when someone requests it on port 80. So this will deny any listing and permissions to them.

Comment: Well, yeah but I have some...files such as images..which i nuse them on the UI, so i need access for the server..

Answer (score 2):

I would add the following to an .htaccess:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from localhost
allow from 127.0.0.1 // incase your loopback isn't configured correctly
allow from 192.168 // incase software isn't using your loopback correctly
```

Hope that helps!